# Does https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token only work for app developers?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

The website tool at:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Can be used by any user to check their token but it seems that the API end point:
https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token

Is only working for app developers.

Firstly I just wanted to confirm this is the case?

Secondly I was wondering if this is so if there is an API end point to check any token? Can't understand why this wouldn't be permitted given that there is a UI/web page feature to do this.

Comment: 1.) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/access-token-debug/ 2.) No.

Comment: 2. yes. Use a `GraphRequest` from the Facebook SDK

Answer (score 6):

Are you asking if the API only works for developers? Yes - As the documentation CBRoe provided shows, you need to include a currently valid `access_token` from your own app in order to debug the details of another one.

That API endpoint does let you check any token from your app, you just need to specify your own token to authenticate the request

Comment: No, Igy, you can not check just any token – it has to be a token tied to your app. Otherwise, you’ll get an exception saying, _“(#100) The App_id in the input_token did not match the Viewing App”_

Comment: Gotcha, i'll correct my answer - didn't realise the app had to match but it makes sense, i don't see why you'd have tokens for another app to begin with

Comment: I'm still not clear, apologies if I am being slow :-/

So I have a user of our app who is trying to check his own token (which is tied to our app) using his own token. So something like this:
graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token=INPUT_TOKEN&access_token=INPUT_TOKEN
  
But he always gets:
"There was an error returned from Facebook. Please ensure you have authenticated. ((#100) )"  

Is this expected? Should only users who are configured as developers of the app be able to run this?

Comment: The intended behaviour is that any access token (including expired or revoked) from app 'A' can be debugged, but the request must be made on behalf of the app, so it requires you to also specify a currently valid token from an admin of app 'A', or the App Access Token for an admin of app A - if that's not working for you please file a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/